# MySql: Store Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database I created for retail store data. I have three tables defined as follows:

*Clients*

```
id
name
```

Items

```
id
name
price
```

Purchases

```
id
client_id
item_id
```

So if the user enters a wrong Item name or price he would go to the item and make changes and it'll be fixed in all purchases (let's call this situation 1), but what if the product company decides to changes price for instance, if the user changes the price in item the previous purchases would changes as well. I thought of including the price in the Purchases table, but then situation 1 would be changing a lot of purchases.

My question is what is the best approach to work around this issue?

***EDIT***

Based on Gordon's comment, I did the following changes:
Items

```
id
name
price_id
```

Prices

```
id
price
effective_date
```

My question now is: I have more than 5000 item, wouldn't this slow my search?

Comment: You should have a `ProductPrice` table with effective and end dates.  This provides the information you need to now the price at any given time.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: You don't really need end dates. Selecting the latest start date will suffice.

Comment: Your current table layout with `effective_date` should do the job. Make sure you create indexes for all relevant tables. Then speed should not be an issue.